# Drupal 8 views template: get current page number

Tags: templates, drupal, view, twig, drupal-8

I am trying to get the pager's current page number inside a views twig template file *views-view-unformatted--categories--page_1.html.twig*

In Drupal 7 I have managed to get the pager's current page through: *$view->query->pager->current_page*

This is exactly what I need to get, but I cannot figure out how to do it in Drupal 8. I have tried **{{ dump() }}** to see what variables are available inside the template, but that ends up in a white screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem. For anyone wondering, you can get the current page number in a view like this: {{ view.pager.current_page }}

Answer (score 0):

if you are using drupal 8, you can use this replacement pattern to get the current page number:
 [view:current-page]